# finite dimensional CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional CW complex, where X is simply connected and at least one $H_{i}(X)$, is non trivial (so that X not be contractible). Can we conclude that X has at least one non trivial  homology group which is finitely generated?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, take for instance the CW complex with a single vertex and an infinite amount of two dimensional simplices, and no other simplices in any dimension.

Comment: @Berci no, I forgot about that, fixed it.

Comment: Then, can we say that at least one homology group $H_{i}(X,\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ is not zero for some prime $p$?

Comment: @user210251 You can do better than that. Hint: Use the splitting property of the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: I did it, but even in this method I have problems. Take for example a complex which has homology $\mathbb{Q}$ in a degree k and 0 otherwise. Then $Tor(H_{k},\mathbb{Q})=0$ AND $H_{k}\otimes \mathbb{Q}=0$